# Bootstrap 2 - set dialog/modal position

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've found one way to do this:

use margins to control dialog position so `margin: -335px 0 0 -280px`;

setting the width you must reset the margins `width: 900px;   margin: -250px 0 0 -450px;`

to set the height use max-height  `max-height: 800px;`
based on

http://www.revillwebdesign.com/change-the-height-width-and-position-of-a-modal-in-twitter-bootstrap/

Is there a better way to do this? Using this or another approach, is there a way to only have the dialog slide down to `top:0px` and stay there until dismissed?

Using the first margin settings I mentioned does this but obviously as soon as the browser is resized it will get pushed out of view.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply override the CSS position, eg

```
.modal, .modal.fade.in {
    top: 0; /* was 10% */
}
```

Note, this is with [Bootstrap 2.2.2](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals). The only margin is a negative left margin that is half the width of the modal (centres the modal horizontally). No top margins are required.

jsFiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/uuwAn/1/

Comment: No unfortunately that didn't work. I updated to 2.2.2 I was on 2.2.1.
It sends the modal off screen - playing with the top:* it takes about 40% for it to be at the top of the screen. anything less and it shoots up

Comment: Thanks for the update @Phil turns out it was the location of the markup. It's a single page App and I put close to the button it's related to without realising it was inside a tag whose css affected it when displayed. Works fine now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the `CSS` at your end to archive this behavior.

```
.modal-body {
    max-height: 350px;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px), (max-height: 450px) {
    .modal-body {
        max-height: 130px;
    }

}
```

Now its will work well on the mobile devices. 
NOTE: done by using Media query of `CSS`.